# Nested If statement

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to write an IF statement for a field called `Status`.  It checks a field called `Tooling`. If the value is `NO`, it just marks the `Status` `Complete`.

If the value of `Tooling` is `Yes`, it then then checks 4 other fields (`T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`).  If any one of them is blank, `Status` should be `Open`.  When all four of the `T` fields = `X`, `Status` should be `Complete`.

I have no idea how to write this.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Made something for you. WF is working. Hope it helps!

**List:**

[image]

**Workflow:**

[image]

I used SharePoint 2013 on-prem and SharePoint Designer with Workflow 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The Key function you need is `OR` so you can check multiple values at once.

Also look into what `CHOOSE` and `ISBLANK` do

All Functions documentation is at:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List